# Apple Watch - Do I need to add a watchkit extension if I want to customise how my remote notifications are delivered?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, watchkit

I'm a bit confused about the wording in this bit of documentation.

> Apps are not required to do anything to support notifications. The system provides a default notification interface that displays the alert message from the notification. However, apps can customize the notification interface and include custom graphics, content, and branding.

I don't have a watch app, but the notifications are received by the watch if it's paired with the iPhone.

Is it possible to customise the watch notification without having a separate watch app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if you want to have a custom notification interface, you'll have to provide a Watch app, too.